# What happens in detail in this bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, git-bash

In according to learn something about bash scripting I found this interesting bash script.

I am curious how this works in detail but I am a beginner in bash scripting.

I understand, that a semicolon seperates several commands and that there are some predefined variables used like `$LINES` and `$RANDOM` and something is being piped later on, but thats it.

And why is it only executable when pasted in one line?

INFO:
*I am using Git Bash on Windows 10*

Maybe someone with experience can do a walk through? Additional explanation is desirable.

```
echo -e "\e[1;40m" ; clear ; while :; do echo $LINES $COLUMNS $(( $RANDOM % $COLUMNS)) $(( $RANDOM % 72 )) ;sleep 0.05; done|awk '{ letters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZﾑｷﾉﾌﾚｱｲ√ﾒﾘ0123456789()₿₹₵иηøρгţчςợгµαϤδχϞϗγπϥ";c=$4; letter=substr(letters,c,1);a[$3]=0;for (x in a) {o=a[x];a[x]=a[x]+1; printf "\033[%s;%sH\033[2;32m%s",o,x,letter; printf "\033[%s;%sH\033[1;37m%s\033[0;0H",a[x],x,letter;if (a[x] >= $1) { a[x]=0; } }}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting script. Let me break down the one-liner for clarity adding some comments with a little modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s checkwinsize                   # bash updates the values of LINES and COLUMNS
echo -e "\e[1;40m"
clear
while :; do
    echo "$LINES" "$COLUMNS" "$(( $RANDOM % $COLUMNS))" "$(( $RANDOM % 72 ))"
    sleep 0.05
done | awk '
    {letters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZﾑｷﾉﾌﾚｱｲ√ﾒﾘ0123456789()₿₹₵иηøρгţчςợгµαϤδχϞϗγπϥ"
    c=$4
    letter=substr(letters, c, 1)        # pick a character from letters in random
    a[$3]=0                             # a[x] holds a row position of column x
                                        # pick a column in random to put a new character
    for (x in a) {                      # loop over the columns which has characters on it
        o=a[x]                          # original row position of column x
        a[x]=a[x]+1                     # increment the row position of column x
                                        # to express the character falls down
        printf "\033[%s;%sH\033[2;32m%s", o, x, letter
        printf "\033[%s;%sH\033[1;37m%s\033[0;0H", a[x], x, letter
        if (a[x] >= $1) {               # if the row position of column x reaches the bottom line
            a[x]=0                      # then reset the row position
        }
    }
}'
```

The escape sequence, the point of the animation, will require additional explanation:

```
echo -e "\e[1;40m"              set the character bold, and the background black

printf "\033[%s;%sH", o, x      move cursor to row "o", column "x"
printf "\033[2;32m%s", letter   put "letter" with dim green color

printf "\033[%s;%sH", a[x], x   move cursor down to row "a[x]", column "x"
printf "\033[1;37m%s", letter   put "letter" with white color
printf "\033[0;0H"              move cursor to the top-left corner
```

Comment: Maybe also note that `tput` is generally better than hard-coding control sequences for a particular terminal.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the useful comment. I do agree on that point.